# Create a function inside ngOnInit without service Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to make a recursive function inside ngOnInit which calls a function from the service. Is it possible?

Something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    myfunction(){
       if(something){
          this.xService.function2(){...}
          myfunction()}
       else{}
    }
 }
```

Comment: why you want to call the function in recursive. can you share your possible scenario.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's possible, just define `myfunction` as a lexical scope function

```
ngOnInit() {
    let myfunction = () => {
        if (something) {
            this.xService.function2(){... }
            myfunction()
        }
        else { }
    }
}
```

or you can also use non lexical, but it may have some issue while referring  `this`

```
ngOnInit() {
    function myfunction(){
        if(something){
            this.xService.function2(){...}
            myfunction()}
        else{}
    }
}
```